# Codeigniter , classe Session é segura?

Tags: codeigniter, session

O Codeigniter possui uma classe própria para Session, isto é, não utiliza as Sessions nativas do PHP.

[Note: The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It generates its own session data, offering more flexibility for developers.](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Voce pode setar uma session da seguinte forma:

```
$data_session = array(
                              'id_login'                    => $id_user,
                              'nome'                         => $nome,
                              'userPermission'                   => 1       
                              );
$this->session->set_userdata($data_session);
```

Minhá dúvida é:

É realmente seguro utilizar esta classe para gravar ID's que deveriam ser secretos?

Existe alguma contra-indicação na qual não deveríamos utilizar esta classe?

Comment: O que você quis dizer com não utilizar sessions nativas? O CodeIgniter o chama de Session Library, como você mesmo pode ver são um conjunto de funções pré-escritas. Podemos acompanhar nesse link (http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data) que `$_SESSION['item']` e `$this->session->item` são a mesma coisa...

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft Se não me engano agora com a versão 3 que o Codeigniter passou a integrar com a superglobal `$_SESSION` do php sendo que nas versões anteriores as sessions do CI eram independentes. Com relação a segurança das sessions, nessa nova versão do CI elas foram reescritas, mas com as versões anteriores você também pode definir algumas configurações de segurança, como expiração da sessão, chave de encriptação entre outras configurações no arquivo `config.php`. Já ouvi várias críticas com relação as sessions do CI, mas é sempre legal configura-la antes.

Comment: @JhonatanOliveira, não sabia que nas versões anteriores eram independentes (Não utilizo CodeIgniter). Fui pesquisar e na documentação encontrei essa informação por isso perguntei o motivo dele falar "não utilizar sessions nativas"... mas obrigado pela informação, sempre é bom saber dessas diferenças. Até seria bom ele adicionar essa informação na pergunta, acho que é bem relevante...

Answer (score 1):

Sem o devido cuidado não!

Você pode setar algumas opções de segurança para a sua Session, como uma chave de encriptação (hash) e modificar o tempo de duração da sessão (por padrão 1 hora).

Uma situação (obviamente) não recomendável é deixar a Sessão ativa após fechar o navegador, que vinha por padrão ativada no arquivo `config.php` ou dados de recuperação;

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que se você usar uma encriptografia (hash) e também , no arquivo `config.php` tornar false a opção de deixar a sessão ativa após o encerramento do navegador